# JPopupmenut not working under linux / Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, jpopupmenu

I was working on a project under windows and it works perfectly, but when I moved it to linux, weird things started to happen. But I won't ask more than one question in this one, Let's start with JPopupmenu not working at all.
Under windows : I have a JTable and JPopupmenu which should be visible inside the JTable, I added the JPopupmenu from swing directly.
Here is the trigger code :

```
private void jTable2MouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    if (evt.isPopupTrigger()) {
        int rows = jTable2.getRowCount();
        if(rows>0){
             JTable source = (JTable) evt.getSource();
        int row = source.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
        int column = source.columnAtPoint(evt.getPoint());

        if (!source.isRowSelected(row)) {
            source.changeSelection(row, column, false, false);
        }
        jPopupMenu1.show(evt.getComponent(), evt.getX(), evt.getY());
        }

    }
}
```

As the code shows: the Popupmenu should be visible when the rows inside JTable greater than zero. It works under windows but noting happen on Linux. What did I miss here ?

Comment: UI in Java is OS dependent. Be sure to use the same java version on both OS.

Comment: Thank you but isn't there any alternative for that ? I mean something will work for any java version ?

Comment: Right now it's just a suggestion to investigate the problem. You can prevent differences between java version like bug fix. So may be it's what's happening in your case.

Comment: OK. I'll reboot to windows to check java version on both OS's and will be back. Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately it's not the problem. Both working with  openjdk version "1.8.0_151"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it, I have to add the same code in JTableMousePressed event and it will work as it should.